# FragmentStatePagerAdapter performance issue

Tags: android, performance, android-viewpager, fragment, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have implemented an activity that displays fragments in a viewpager. The activity initially displays 5 fragments of a given type (type A). Each type A fragment contains a list of information. When a button is pressed, the fragments are replaced with another tpye of fragments, type B (i.e., fragments that use a different layout and display different information are loaded).

I have implemented this with a ViewPager and a custom FragmentStatePagerAdapter. The custom FragmentStatePagerAdapter overrides the getCount, instantiateItem, getItem, getItemPosition, etc. functions and all works fine. When I press the button the views switch from fragment type A to fragment type B. In order to do this I am using a replace fragment transaction and I also call notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter. The switch from type A to type B fragments is accomplished by checking which type of fragment I need to create in the adapter's getItem function. The problem is that the switching process (i.e., changing from fragment type A to fragment type B and vice versa) takes some time (around 2 seconds) - this delay is quite noticeable and annoying.

This occurs because the adapter's getItemPosition function returns POSITION_NONE. When POSITION_NONE is returned, the viewPager recreates the fragment. Furthermore, when the replace transaction is executed, all items of the adapter are removed and all new ones are recreated. The same happens when I switch back to fragments type A.

Does anyone know if there is a better or faster way to do this? Using a FragmentPagerAdapter should not be a good solution since the number of fragments in the viewPager could grow.

I have commented out the updating of the fragments and the problem is gone so the problem is the time it takes to update the fragments. Is there a way to update the fragments asynchronously? That should take care of the problem.

Comment: As I understand you have two levels of `Fragments`. Why you don't instantiate a second `ViewPager` for your `Fragments` of Type B? Than you have for each level an own `ViewPager` and `FragmentStatePageAdapter` and you don't have  to take care of which `Fragment` has to be instantiated.

Comment: Fragments of type A display a list of values. Fragments of type B display a graph that corresponds to each set of values. For example, I have sales for location 1, sales for location 2, etc, up to location 5. When I click the button, the sales figures are replaced by the sales graph for location 1, 2, 3 .. 5. If I am viewing sales for location 4 and tap the button, I go to the sales chart for location 4. Swiping to the left or right will take me to chart 5 or 3. The way it is now works, the problem is the speed. Am I missing something? What if I need to display 50 locations at some point?

Comment: I don't think you have to worry about the count of locations you want to display. The Api of the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` says: "This version of the pager is more useful when there are a large number of pages, working more like a list view. When pages are not visible to the user, their entire fragment may be destroyed, only keeping the saved state of that fragment. This allows the pager to hold on to much less memory associated with each visited page as compared to FragmentPagerAdapter at the cost of potentially more overhead when switching between pages. "

Comment: You say you have a problem with the speed...Do you mean the time to swipe or the time a `Fragment` is instantiated. Perhaps you have to reorganize your LocationFragments and check where you can save some time to instantiate the data.

Comment: The speed problem is in the time it takes from the moment I tap the button (that changes the type of fragments) until the new type of fragment appears - this is because the new type of fragment will not be displayed until all fragments are created.

Comment: mmh...I also use the `ViewPager` with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and it doesn't instatiate all `Fragments`, it just instantiate the left and right one of the current one. Did you set the OffScreenPageLimit? Please read this in the `ViewPager` API: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29. The value should be set by default to a minimum count...

Comment: You are absolutely right about the OffScreenPageLimit settings. I had set it to the total number of pages to display in order for page swiping to be smooth and I forgot about it. Setting it to 1 (default value) solves the issue of creating all pages. There is still a small delay though so I think I should do the drawing in each fragment in an AsyncTask. Is there a better solution?

Comment: I answered your question. So it will be easier for other users to get the solution of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ViewPager` instatiates by default a minimun count of `Fragments`. In general the left and right one of the current `Fragment`. So you don't need to care about the total number of `Fragments`.

You can control the total number with the [`ViewPager.setOffScreenPageLimit()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29) method.

Also a [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) seems to be a good idea to manage the intensiv work of your `Fragments`.